# What are some good Content Auditing tools or practices around the web?

Tags: content-audit, content-strategy

I was wondering if there are any other tools out there for content audits. Currently I use MS Excel to create my document which is pretty barebones.

If anyone has any suggestions, resources or best practices that would be great!

Comment: [Requests for products](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are unsuitable for a Q&A site because they have no one correct answer and quickly become outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on many project with Excel for auditing and most of the time it worked great. But depending of the context, type of audit, will of your team to learn new tools you might find something from the list below that will work great for you.

**Mantis**

I've worked a lot with Mantis. Straightforward to use, almost no learning curve. You can create different project/release, log and assign bug etc.

**Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) and Team Fundation Server (TFS)**

Currently working with this. It might be a little overkill and with a more steep learning curve for you and your team. You can report bug, manage your project and your team, generate report etc.

**Jira**

If worked briefly with Jira. From my point of view, it's quite similar to MTM/TFS you might want to take a look and see if it fits your needs. It's a collaborative tool for bug tracking and project management.